# Replacing child react component with another based on user intreaction or button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I have created bootstrap modal component in react.

```
        var carModal=<Modal handleHideModal={this.handleHideCarModal}
                onConfirm={this.confirmCarModal}
                title="Car"
                id="CarModal">
                <CarStructure callbackParent={this.showCarOptionsUpdate}/>
                </Modal>
```

In car structure I have a form where based on button click I want to remove `<CarStructure>` child component from the modal `carModal` and update it with another component with different form structure. How can I replace `<CarStructure>` with another component having totally different user interface and options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that the job of a React component's `render` function is to describe how the component should look *at any given point at time*, so you don't "remove" or "change" pieces of the DOM so much as you describe when they should change *themselves*. So, you'll want to base the internal component of `<Modal>` on some sort of state (which may change throughout the life of the parent component). Something like this might do the trick:

```
var carModalBody;
if (this.state.something) {
  var carModalBody = <CarStructure callbackParent={this.showCarOptionsUpdate} />;
} else {
  var carModalBody = <SomeOtherComponent />;
}

var carModal = <Modal handleHideModal={this.handleHideCarModal}
                      onConfirm={this.confirmCarModal}
                      title="Car"
                      id="CarModal">
                        {carModalBody}
               </Modal>
```